uninitialized variable in Bash condition unexpectedly true
I've got the following script:
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ${DISABLE_WORK} -ne "0" ]];
then
    echo "exiting"
    exit 0
fi

echo "doing something"

The output is:
case 1:
$ DISABLE_WORK=1 ./if.sh 
exiting

case 2:
$ DISABLE_WORK=2 ./if.sh 
exiting

case 3:
$ DISABLE_WORK=0 ./if.sh 
doing something

case 4:
$ ./if.sh 
doing something

I searched the documentation and still can not figure out why case 4 produces 'doing something' instead of 'exiting'. Could someone explain, please?

@pmf that doesn't explain why it says "doing something". As you said, '' is different from '0', therefore it ought to say "exiting".

@k314159 True. -ne induces a numeric comparison, rendering the empty string to 0. A string comparison using == would fail, and print "doing something".

-ne is an arithmetic operator. Inside [[...]] its operands are evaluated as arithmetic expressions. In an arithmetic context the empty string evaluates to zero. An unset variable expands to the empty string.
If you don't want that you can use a string comparison operator instead. Like:
[[ $DISABLE_WORK != 0 ]]


On the surface, this is because an empty string is not treated as numerically zero.
The question is, what you really want to do. If you want to interpret an empty/nonexistent variable identical to a variable containing 0, you can do
if (( DISABLE_WORK == 0 ))

Note that you must not write a $ here.
If you want to test, whether the variable is empty or non-existent, you can do a
if [[ -z $DISABLE_WORK ]]

I didn't find a reasonable strategy for distinguishing an unset / undefined variable from an empty one. If just want to print an error message if it is unset, you can do it like this:
: ${DISABLE_WORK:?exiting}

which prints exiting, if the variable is unset, and terminates. If the variable is empty, it continues.
I personally impose in my scripts the requirement, that all variables need to be defined before being used, and do a
set -u

initially to enforce this. This prints an error message, whenever I use an undefined variable - very helpful during debugging! If I then want to treat a certain undefined variable explicitly as null - this is typically when my script allows an optional environment variable set in the parent process -, I do a
: ${DISABLE_WORK:=}

If DISABLE_WORK existed before, it remains unchanged. If it did not exist, it is created and defined as the null string.

The important point for your question is that bash's default behavior is to treat an unset variable as an empty string, and an empty string in a numeric context as zero; these defaults can be damned handy, but can also seem like spooky action in secret when they aren't quite what you expected. You can, as mentioned, alter those defaults with things like set -u which makes use of any unset variable an error.
[[...]] generally handles string comparisons and ((...)) handles math, but doing math comparisons like -ne in [[...]] constructs can easily get your brain contextually tangled (though it can also be a good way to leverage those defaults.)
In this case, as oguz ismail mentioned, your structure uses the undefined variable in a context that treats empty as zero, and compares it to a quoted string zero, both of which get processed to a mathematical zero and evaluated as equal by -ne.
As one addition to user1934428's comment:
if (( DISABLE_WORK == 0 ))


Note that you must not write a $ here.

He makes a very good and very important point, but I'd point out that it's because if you use an empty variable in that context it is evaluated in one pass (as a string) before being put into the mathematical context in another. This means you totally can use the $ version of a variable, and all the tools it brings, but be aware of what's happening.
$: set -x 
$: x=0; (( x == 0 )) && : ok || : no
+ x=0
+ ((  x == 0  ))
+ : ok
$: (( "$x" == 0 )) && : ok || : no # quotes don't help much here 
+ ((  0 == 0  ))
+ : ok
$: x=1; (( x == 0 )) && : ok || : no
+ x=1
+ ((  x == 0  ))
+ : no
$: (( $x == 0 )) && : ok || : no
+ ((  1 == 0  ))
+ : no
$: unset x
+ unset x
$: (( x == 0 )) && : ok || : no # unset defaults to zero
+ ((  x == 0  ))
+ : ok
$: (( "$x" == 0 )) && : ok || : no # *empty string* is syntax error!
+ ((   == 0  ))
bash: ((: == 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== 0 ")
+ : no
$: (( "${x:-0}" == 0 )) && : ok || : no # default to true
+ ((  0 == 0  ))
+ : ok
$: (( "${x:-1}" == 0 )) && : ok || : no # default to false
+ ((  1 == 0  ))
+ : no

You can use indirection if it helps.
$: y=0
+ y=0
$: (( ${x:-y} == 0 )) && : ok || : no # look closely!
+ ((  y == 0  ))
+ : ok
$: y=1
+ y=1
$: (( ${x:-y} == 0 )) && : ok || : no # defaulting to y
+ ((  y == 0  ))
+ : no
$: unset y
+ unset y
$: (( ${x:-y} == 0 )) && : ok || : no # ok with y unset
+ ((  y == 0  ))
+ : ok
$: x=1 # won't use y here, as x has a value
+ x=1
$: (( ${x:-y} == 0 )) && : ok || : no # uses *value* of x 
+ ((  1 == 0  ))
+ : no

Some Options (Aside from the above)
If you want to be explicit, you can chain tests.
(Also, I know that sometimes you have to, but when possible it's a good idea to avoid negative tests.)
if [[ "$DISABLE_WORK" == "0" || "$DISABLE_WORK" == "" ]]
then echo "Exiting."
     exit 1
else echo "doing stuff"
fi

As mentioned, defaulting certain values is another good approach.
if [[ "${DISABLE_WORK:-0}" == "0" ]]
then echo "Exiting."
     exit 1
else echo "doing stuff"
fi

You can get very similar results with a regex -
if [[ "$DISABLE_WORK" =~ ^[^0]+$ ]]
then echo "doing stuff"
else echo "Exiting."
     exit 1
fi

And of course a case statement.
case "$DISABLE_WORK" in
0|"") echo "Exiting."; exit 1 ;;
   *) echo "doing stuff"      ;;
esac

In everything, context is king.
